# Gmail sent email extraction

Tags: python, smtp, gmail, imap, extract

I am trying to extract the mails from the sent label of gmail but I cannot. I have extracted the mails from inbox and don't know how to extract from the sent label.

```
# Importing libraries 
import imaplib, smtplib, pathlib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


imap_url = 'imap.gmail.com'

# Function to get email content part i.e its body part 
def get_body(msg): 
    if msg.is_multipart(): 
        return get_body(msg.get_payload(0)) 
    else: 
        return msg.get_payload(None, True) 

# Function to search for a key value pair  
def search(key, value, con):  
    result, data = con.search(None, key, '"{}"'.format(value))
    return data 

# Function to get the list of emails under this label 
def get_emails(result_bytes): 
    msgs = [] # all the email data are pushed inside an array 
    for num in result_bytes[0].split(): 
        typ, data = con.fetch(num, '(RFC822)') 
        msgs.append(data) 

    return msgs 

# this is done to make SSL connnection with GMAIL 
con = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_url)  

# logging the user in 
con.login(user, password)  

# calling fuction to check for email under this label 
con.select('Inbox')  

# fetching emails from this user "tu**h*****1@gmail.com" 
msgs = get_emails(search('FROM', 'demo@gmail.com', con))
```

Comment: Find the name of the Sent folder you account, and select that, not Inbox.  It is language specific.

Comment: I got the name for sent label. "[Gmail]/Sent Mail"